# QT6.2 QtQuick.Studio.Components Debug and Release version and select (Cannot mix debug and release version)

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

**What I would like to archive:**

Use QtQuick.Studio.Components in Debug and Release build version in my Application.

Operation system: Windows10

**What I did:**

I'm using in the Qt QML Application (Community Version) the QtQuick.Studio.Components based on the description I had to build the module manually, because the Project is using qmake instead of cmake.

The build steps are described here:

https://codereview.qt-project.org/gitweb?p=qt-labs/qtquickdesigner-components.git;a=blob;f=README.md;h=a9f4c6244be7c2f2e2ef1e85c3b03b62eed5d4d7;hb=HEAD

````
   1 # Qt Design Studio QML modules
   2 
   3 These modules provide the types  
   4 
   5 # Usage
   6 
   7 The modules get installed into Qt and provide the respective imports for QML.
   8 
   9 # Building
  10 
  11 ```
  12 mkdir build
  13 cd build
  14 cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=path_to_qt_install_directory path_to_qtquickdesigner-components_cmake
  15 cmake --build .
  16 cmake --install .
  17 ```
  18 
  19 This will install the Qt Design Studio modules in your Qt installation directory.
````

My command adjusted to my paths are `cmake -GNinja --DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\  C:\temp\designer2\qtquickdesigner-components`

If I build my Application in QtCreator as Debug then I don't get an error message.
If I build my Application in QtCreator as Release then I get the error message:

```
'C:/Qt/6.4.1/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Studio/Components/quickstudiocomponentsplugind.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)
```

**Questions:**

- How I build the plugin as Release and Debug?
- How I have to define the install prefix, because I cannot find a Qt Debug or Qt Release Version in my installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build it two times. Unfortunately, there was a bug that pretended reconfiguration.

a fix is here https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt-labs/qtquickdesigner-components/+/453366

Note: If you already installed a version, you need to remove the newly generated files at:
<path_to_qt_install_directory>/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/QmlPlugins
(sort by date to see which files went into it via your last qtquickdesigner-components build)

```
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=path_to_qt_install_directory -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release path_to_qtquickdesigner-components_cmake && cmake --build . && cmake --install .
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=path_to_qt_install_directory -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug path_to_qtquickdesigner-components_cmake && cmake --build . && cmake --install .
```